# How to Mock AzureServiceTokenProvider

Tags: c#, azure, unit-testing, azure-functions

I have a function which gets the access token from the AppIdUri. This function calls inside my business logic. While Unit testing the logic GetAccessToken is returning null. I need to mock this  AzureServiceTokenProvider inorder to Pass the testcase. AzureServiceTokenProvider does not have an Interface. Does anyone knows how to Mock AzureServiceTokenProvider.

```
private async Task<string> GetAccessToken()
        {
            var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
            string accessToken = await azureServiceTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync($"{AppIdUri}");
            return accessToken;
        }
```

Comment: When this happens - which is often - you may need to create your own abstraction which you can mock, and then have an implementation which wraps the class you can't mock.,

Comment: Do you have implementation for GetAccessTokenAsync function so that I can implement manually and create a interface to mock those

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to mock something that doesn't implement an interface and the method you want to mock isn't virtual, one option is to wrap it in your own interface which can be mocked.

As an example for `AzureServiceTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync(string)`:

```cs
public interface ITokenProvider
{
    Task<string> GetTokenAsync(string resource);
}
```

And then an implementation:

```cs
public class AzureTokenProvider : ITokenProvider
{
    public async Task<string> GetTokenAsync(string resource)
    {
        var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
        string token = await azureServiceTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync(resource);
        return token;        ​
   ​}
}
```

This allows you to inject your interface - `ITokenProvider` - which you can mock.